# Load a page with loading indicator - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a hook useAsync (copied from https://usehooks.com/). Whenever an api fires, it gives me loading ,error , success etc.

I am doing a mock of network call in useEffect , so that the request fires.
I want to show loading indicator from the moment , the page loads and till the mock of network call resolves

If you see the code sandbox link , you can see the initial View which is not loading indicator , then it changes to loading .

Is there any easy way to show loading indicator immediately on page load. I can keep one more state variable , but not sure if it is correct way or better way exists

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-ishizaka-9blti?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Just add a loading component right before displaying your main jsx logic. You can make loader show up only when `status` is `pending`, thus rendering that component on page load, like so:

```js
function App() {
  const { execute, status, value, error } = useAsync(myFunction, false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    execute();
  }, []);

  if (status === "pending") {
    return (
      <p>
        Loading....
      </p>
    )
  }

  return (
   // your main jsx
  );
}
```